# CentOS: What package includes X file

Tags: centos, package-management, search

On CentOS, using yum, or another software (text mode). How can I search for a package, for example to search for the package that includes `smbclient`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo yum whatprovides *bin/smbclient
```

Comment: To save a few keystrokes, `yum provides */smbclient` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `yum search TEXT`.

You can look at `rpm -qf /path/to/file` to determine which already-installed package contains a particular file. (or what package said file belongs to)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned you can use `yum whatprovides /path/to/file`. That will list all the packages which potentially could provide you the file (installed, updates. base, etc).

However if you would like to find just the current package which provides the file on your system I prefer to use `rpm -qf path/to/file`, because the result is much clean :)

For example if you use `yum` for `/bin/cp`:

```
# yum whatprovides /bin/cp
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
...
coreutils-8.4-19.el6.i686 : A set of basic GNU tools commonly used in shell scripts
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /bin/cp

coreutils-8.4-16.el6.i686 : A set of basic GNU tools commonly used in shell scripts
Repo        : installed
Matched from:
Other       : Provides-match: /bin/cp
```

If you use `rpm` for `/bin/cp`:

```
# rpm -qf /bin/cp
coreutils-8.4-16.el6.i686
```

Comment: How do you know the full path of the command if it is not installed?